# Как отключить schedule при условии? python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, schedule

Пишу тг бота на библиотеке  telebot
Пытаюсь сделать рассылку пользователю, если он выбирает "да", то ему каждый день присылается сообщение, если выбирает "нет" то рассылка либо отключается, либо просто не включается

```
if message.text == "Подборка книг":
    podborka = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Да", callback_data="да")
    no = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Нет", callback_data="нет")
    podborka.add(yes,no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Получать рассылку?", reply_markup=podborka)
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
    def callback_inline(call):
        def good_luck():
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Круто!")
        job = schedule.every(1).seconds.do(good_luck)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

        if call.message:
            if call.data == "да":
                godo()
            else:
                schedule.cancel_job(job)
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)